# What is the word for when you are about to walk into someone and hesitate whether to move left or right?

Tags: phrase-requests

When you are about to walk into someone (generally a stranger), you anticipatory move, say left, to avoid a crash. The other person too does the same but to his right. So in essence the anticipation on both sides was futile (your left is his right). Then you go right and the other guy responds with a left. This carries on twice or thrice until it ends with a smile and a consensus as to which way to go. Finally you part ways.

This whole 'process' seems very intriguing to me and I'm sure has not just happened to me, hence, I expect there must be some word for it.

Comment: I have no idea, but from now on I think we should call it a *Polisetty Dance*.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a dance.  And there's a variety of the thing, where only one "partner" is actively participating, which should probably be called a "smartphone dance".